# Assessment on SpreadJs and Handsontable.

Tags: javascript, handsontable, wijmo

I am trying to implement dashboard where i need to have HTML 5 spreadsheet ,which will be dynamic in nature, into my webpage/dashboard, i was looking into [Spreads](http://wijmo.com/products/spreadjs/) and [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/).

I still need to decide which one i will go with... If some has already used any of these, can you please tell me what are the pros and cons and which one should i go with?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's a broad question, hard to answer. You don't specify what it's for or any other constraints. You didn't tell us how the data is inputted, how it gets validated, how it gets transformed, etc...

In short though, Handsontable is more lightweight than Spreads and easier to modify. However, it's less 'pretty' and requires more setting up as it uses table tags rather than a canvas. Not to mention one is free and the other isn't.

That's all the help I can give with such limited information.

Answer (score 0):

Let me begin by pointing out some of the obvious differences between HandsOnTable and SpreadJS.

Think about your support options.

SpreadJS is a paid product and you can purchase maintenance with the license that is good for a year.  This includes live phone support if you need assistance with the control, something that HandsOnTable doesn't offer.

I also noticed so major differences in formulas.  I encourage you to browse through the formulas offered by SpreadJS located here
[SpreadJS Formula Demo](http://wijmo.com/demo/spreadjs/samples/ExplorerSample/?widget=Formulas&sample=Formulas)  
and plug those into the HandsOnTable sample here
[HandsOnSample](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) `enter code here`

and you will notice that HandsOn doesnt support basic formula functionality.

SpreadJS has a complement component, ExeclIO, that is a webservice ( only supported in IIS ) that handles Excel workbook conversions and sends the JSON ( ssjson ) back to the client and loaded into the excel sheet.  I am not sure how well HandsOn handles Excel conversions and if it does, I don't think the client will be able to handle the load of converting some large workbooks.

If you want to list some more specifics I will be glad to answer.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention in this post that you work for the company that develops SpreadJS.

Comment: Wow, this is the most blatant software promotion I've seen on this site lol

Comment: The user asked a question asking for pros/cons comparing two specific software tools.    The user asked for input from those knowledgeable with the tools, input, which I gave.